# problem with 'zoomend'

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to turn on/off some layers according to zoom level, my code are like this

```
    map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map', options,
            {div: "map", 
             allOverlays: true
             });
      var vaga_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Road",
                "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/wms/wsNYCRoad", {
                layers: 'vagar_alla_p',
                styles: '', 
                transparent:true,
                tiled: 'false'
            },
            {
                buffer: 0,
                displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                isBaseLayer: false
            });

       var jvg_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Railway",
                "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/wms/wsNYCRoad", {
                layers: 'jvg_p',
                styles: '', 
                transparent:true,
                tiled: 'false',
            },
            {
                buffer: 0,
                displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                isBaseLayer: false
            });

       var building1_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Building",
                "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/wms/wsNYCRoad", {
                layers: 'bygg_lant_p,bygg_off_p,bygg_ovr_p',
                styles: '', 
                transparent:true,
                tiled: 'false'
            },
            {
                buffer: 0,
                displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                isBaseLayer: false
            });
map.addLayers([gmap,ghyb,gsat,gphy,jvg_wms,vaga_wms,building1_wms,vectors]);
    .
    .
    .
    map.events.register('zoomend', this, function (event) {
                    var zLevel = map.getZoom();     
                    if( zLevel == 1 || zLevel == 2 || zLevel == 3)
                    {
                        jvg_wms.setVisibility(false);
                        vaga_wms.setVisibility(false);
                        building1_wms.setVisibility(false); 

                    }
                     if( zLevel == 4 || zLevel == 5 || zLevel == 6)
                    {
                        jvg_wms.setVisibility(ture);
                        vaga_wms.setVisibility(ture);
                        building1_wms.setVisibility(ture); 
                         map.addLayers([gmap,ghyb,gsat,gphy,jvg_wms,vaga_wms,building1_wms,vectors]);
                    }
                    });
```

These 3 layers indeed turned off when zoom levels are smaller than 4, however, they couldn't turn on when zoomed in .

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: If tomfumb answered your question, please consider accepting it. See more on: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the following lines

```
jvg_wms.setVisibility(ture);
vaga_wms.setVisibility(ture);
building1_wms.setVisibility(ture);
```

`ture` should be `true`